# Responsive web design pure css centering help

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having trouble getting the sponsors sections of the following website to center correctly, I'm using responsive webdesign, and having trouble the  sponsors to center correctly.

Thanks...

http://dev.marshallareastagecompany.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your sponsors div a width, or `margin:0 auto` doesn't know how to compute the position. Give it a width of 1315px, and see how it moves.

Comment: Although by giving the container a fixed width, aren't you making the design less "responsive"?

Comment: @w3d You're right, it's probably better to use a percentage width to keep the site responsive - so `width: 90%` instead of `width: 1315px` for instance.

Comment: You could also use @media in your CSS to change the width at different screen sizes. The main point, here, is that to get anything to auto-center using margin:0 auto, you have to know its width, whether specified in % or in px.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping to avoid fixed widths, or even percentages, but its certainly an option with media queries...

Answer (score 2):

Goto http://dev.marshallareastagecompany.org/public/css/pages/index.css
and find rule `#sponsors ul` (most probably on line 128)

```
#sponsors ul{
  padding:0px;
}
```

Add property `text-align:center` so that final style looks like:

```
#sponsors ul{
  padding:0px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Tested on FF and Chrome with Firebug, and working fine...!!!

Another way is to add a width to `#sponsors` or `#sponsors ul` and assign property `margin:0 auto`.

Comment: It doesn't feel right to me to add `text-align:center` in order to center non-textual elements?

Comment: @w3d : `text-align` property is not intended to align text only contents. It describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. According to the CSS specification, it applies to inline content of a block element. This implies that you aren't just limited to aligning text - that the text-align property can be used to align any element within a block level element.

Comment: This seems to work, however on my screen, the bottom incomplete row, aligns itself center, which is not as desirable...

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your stylesheet:

```
#sponsors ul { text-align: center; }
#sponsors ul li { display: inline-block; }
```

should work.

Comment: yes, but IE7 is not exacly on responsive radar and for older IE browsers just use very simple styling or conditional one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in some of the comments, the best way to retain responsiveness is to use @media to conditionally apply a margin to the primary division.

Let's say we're wanting to use a 960px division. At the bottom of the grid css file.

```
@media (min-width:980px) {
.pure-g {width:960px;margin:0 auto;}
}
```

As soon as the max width drops below 980, the layout would effectively become fluid against the left margin. The extra 20px is buffer to allow for the vertical scroll bar.